# R raster band combination not showing rgb

Tags: r, rgb, r-raster, sentinel

I want to compose an rgb image with channels from different images.

I have the following three source files (.png)(Sentinel 2 satellite images)

[blue band](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNFaK.png), [red band](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lur8i.png), [green band](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMXng.png)

With the following code, I try to build the new image.

```
install.packages('raster')
library('raster')

red <- raster('C:/Users/xy/Desktop/red.png')
green <- raster('C:/Users/xy/Desktop/green.png')
blue <-raster('C:/Users/xy/Desktop/blue.png')

s <- stack(blue,green,red)
plotRGB(s, r=3, g=2, b=1)
```

The basic Idea is: Taking the first band from each png-source file. 
Assigning the bands to R, G and B.

This is the result of the procedure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTK9Q.png)

But the result is not the expected true color image:

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8ybG.png)

I already talked with much more experienced R-users. 
All said, that it should work, but it does not :-(

I would be glad if someone could point out my error or could provide an idea for a solution.

Comment: I don't see much brightness in your green band.  Maybe you need to apply some sort of gamma curve to the bands.

Comment: @dwilliss Thank you very much for pointing this out! Something I have to think about! Maybe the expected result is not composed from the raw data... mhh

Comment: you could try `plotRGB(s, r=3, g=2, b=1, stretch = "lin")`, or `plotRGB(s, r=3, g=2, b=1, stretch = "hist")`

Comment: @LoBu Your answer leaded to an better result. The next days I will do some further tests and report the results :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see it works.

Let's zoom in the area with data:

```
e <- extent(c(95, 160, 0, 62))
s <- crop(s, e)
```

Now inspect

```
plot(s)
```

And

```
pairs(s)
```

What you see is that the values in the three channels are almost identical. If you have near identical values for R, G, and B in a pixel you get a gray color (something between white and black). That is what you get, and that is consistent with your data. There probably is an issue with your data.

Comment: Thank you for your time and sharing your knowledge! Currently I also think that it is more a data problem. I will go into deep the next days and will let you know the results :)